# Why returned false when using booleancheckTimeseriesExists for existed time series in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I checked the time series in Apache IoTDB, and it exists. However, when I use the `booleancheckTimeseriesExists(String path)` method to query certain data results for this time series, the results returned to be false.

Why did this error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you give a specific time series in `booleancheckTimeseriesExists` of Apache IoTDB (not a root name or device name). If not, you need to switch to give a specific time series to get the result.